# Image Processing OpenCV, Need to translate red channel of image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am a beginner in Image processing, and am learning how to maniplulate RGB. I need to translate the red channel for a "corrputed image" to achieve the original image. I am struggling to correctly understand what exactly needs to be done & how to do it, this is what I have achieved so far:

The "Corrputed" and OG image are attatched.

[image: Corrupted]

[image: Original]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("mandrill1.jpg",1)

translated_image = np.zeros_like(image)
translated_image[:, :, 0] = image[:, :, 0]  # Blue channel
translated_image[:, :, 1] = image[:, :, 1]  # Green channel

red_shift = 100
shifted_red_channel = np.clip(image[:, :, 2] + red_shift, 0, 255)

translated_image[:, :, 2] = shifted_red_channel



cv2.imwrite("mandrill1C.jpg", translated_image)
```

I have previously defined what i tried

Comment: [`np.roll()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) looks like it will do the trick.

Comment: Half of it is solved perfectly with np.roll indeed. But the other half (the fact that we find a copy of the eyes in the bottom area of read image, which also means that we don't find what should be there... That is missing information)